# Makefile: gcc line does not show up

Tags: gcc, makefile

If i run the line with `make target_name`:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTS) $(TARGET) &> gcc_log_file
```

i get the following result in the gcc_log_file : nothing
it is strange because if i type  `make -n target_name`, the line is well expanded.

I could add '-v' to gcc but this will be quite ugly, i just want the GCC line to be expanded...

I tried the following workarounds

```
@echo "$(OBJ) $$($(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTS) $(TARGET))" &> gcc_log_file

@printf "$(OBJ) %s\n" $$($(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTS) $(TARGET)) &> gcc_log_file
```

the CC line is executed, $(OBJ) is expanded but not the CC line...

I should precise explicitly that I want to do this inside the makefile, because I don't want to log in the gcc_log_file lines that are not produced by gcc...My makefiles are quite complexes.

any hints?

note that my gcc is a special one, based on gcc 5.2, but i reckon this behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is normal. Whatever `COMMAND` is, `COMMAND &> FILE` executes `COMMAND` and redirects its standard and error outputs to file `FILE`. But in your case `COMMAND` is a compilation command and if there are no errors or warnings your compiler does not print anything on stdout or stderr. So, what is redirected to your log file is nothing at all.

You can check this very easily:

```
$ echo 'int main(void) { return 0; }' > foo.c
$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$
```

See? No output of any kind that you could send to a log file.

While if you `make -n` it is make (not your compiler) that echoes the recipe it would pass to the shell without the -n option. If you want to log your recipes you must echo them yourself in another recipe with, for instance, the `echo` command that sends its shell-expanded parameters to the standard output:

```
target: prerequisites
    @echo "COMMAND" >> log_file
    COMMAND
```

Example:

```
foo: foo.c
    @echo '$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<' >> log_file
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

If you do not want to type the same command twice you can declare a make variable:

```
COMPILATION = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

foo: foo.c
    @echo '$(COMPILATION)' >> log_file
    $(COMPILATION)
```

Or, all at once:

```
COMPILATION = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
ECHOCOMPILE = echo '$(COMPILATION)' >> log_file; $(COMPILATION)

foo: foo.c
    @$(ECHOCOMPILE)
```

(remove the leading `@` if you want make to echo the recipe when passing it to the shell).

Pay attention to the variable assignment operator (`=`). Do not use the simple assignment operator (`:=`), it would not work for reasons that are out of scope this question.

Note that, by default, make echoes the recipes (if you do not prepend a `@`). So, you could as well redirect the output of make:

```
$ cat Makefile
foo: foo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
$ make &> log_file
$ cat log_file
gcc -o foo foo.c
```

Comment: of course, but the (implicit) question was 'how to do that inside the make?'... because i don't want to log evertything, just the GCC line

Comment: Well, as explained, you must add yourself the `echo` recipe to the same rule.

Comment: "_your solution does not work_" is not very helpful. Which solution? What did you do? What did you get?

Comment: ***which solution?*** -- the only one that you provided.I got nothing, as the lines in my post tell.

Comment: doing ```echo "COMMAND"```` or ```@echo "COMMAND"``` does not work

Comment: `echo "COMMAND"` was just a template. Of course you must replace `COMMAND` by the actual command you want to log. Look at the example below which echoes `'$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<'`. I suspect there is a misunderstanding here. Can you explain what you would like to find in your log file? The compilation command itself, with all make variables expanded (in which case the `echo` solution does this)? Or the output of the compilation command (in which case you will not see anything because there is no output at all)?

Comment: ok, it works if I write  the command twice (i was using a var to be expanded but the expansion is not working). Kind of dirty but works.

Comment: Why dirty? This is how the shell works: it does not echo its commands when executing them. And, I my opinion, this is a good default choice because in most cases you do not want to be polluted by log messages. It is when you do want logs that you must do something special. And this has not much to do with make. The recipes are shell scripts that make just passes to the shell without knowing what they do. If you want a script that writes something in a file you must write the script accordingly.

Comment: Your solution with a variable was probably not working because you mixed-up between shell and make variables and omitted to escape something in your recipe. And it could also be that you do not know that recipe lines are executed in different shells so you cannot pass shell variables from one script to the next... I'll update my answer to show how to use a make variable instead.

Comment: thank you for this update. I'd really appreciate an example

Comment: Done. Two examples.